# Code out of nowhere

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting

When I'm reviewing suggested edits, edits such as these get rejected almost instantly because it looks like the code is appearing out of nowhere!

[image]

This isn't actually the case, it's just when the code isn't properly formatted, it doesn't even show up at all, this causes suggested edits from users that improve questions to get rejected.

Could we have the suggested edits default on `side-by-side-markdown` instead of `inline` or `side-by-side`?

[image]

Comment: I don't like reviewing in side-by-side markdown unless necessary.  Why should I be punished because someone isn't being thorough enough

Comment: In addition to Robert's excellent suggestion (which you should be doing anyway), anyone who has sufficient reputation to approve suggested edits should already have seen this enough times to know what is happening: unescaped HTML gets stripped by the markdown renderer.

Comment: I imagine if you would want your edit approved, you would need to make use of the edit description. I think I've had a few edits reverted because of this actually, because it does at the glance look like a huge addition of random stuff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add the words "Fixed code formatting" in the edit summary description, instead of relying on the canned "added x characters to body" description, and the rejections will go way down.